# iOS Core Data data insert

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an app which asynchronously downloads a JSON file and then it should insert those objects within Core Data for persistent storage. Regarding the insert, is it a good idea to do it from the main thread? What if there are thousands of objects? Should I do the inserts on a different thread? Could you provide me with some snippets regarding this matter? Regarding the fetching of the objects after I've saved them, should I also use a different thread?

My code for inserting into Core Data is:

```
- (void) insertObjects:(NSArray*)objects ofEntity:(NSString *)entityName
{
    NSString *key;
    NSManagedObject *managedObject;
    NSError *error;
    for(NSDictionary *dict in objects){
        managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

        for(key in dict){
            [managedObject setValue:dict[key] forKey:key];
        }
    }
    [_managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

PS: The objects are of the same entity. The project runs on iOS 7.0 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet..

What iOS Versions do you plan to support? If 5 and higher, this might help [Concurrency stack](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/2/the-concurrent-core-data-stack)

Summary of the link:

1. you create a context of private concurreny type to access your physical data
2. based on this you create a context of main concurreny type
3. on top of this you use private concurrency type stores again.

Don't forget so save in every store, otherwise, the data seems to be saved while the app is running, but after restart it is lost.

And yes, you want to do it an extra thread, since it would otherwise block the UI if there are to many items.

Comment: You can always use the worker context for fetching. For small amounts of data it is not necessary, but doesn't hurt either.